# .Net Core 2.x Redirect to Error Page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, custom-error-handling

I have a simple ASP.Net Core 2.0 web application and I have enabled Windows Authentication in project property by enabling Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication.

For Authorization at Application/Site level filtering by AD security group, I have the following code in Startup.cs:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .RequireRole("Application - Administrator")
                                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");
        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

To handle Http 403 status code when a un-authorized user tries to access the application, it will be redirect to a custom error page. So I tried the following 3 approaches in Configure method within Startup.cs:

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
```

In the HomeController, I tried both the default Error method

```cs
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

and customized one to handle specific status code:

```cs
public IActionResult Error(string errCode)
{
    if (errCode == "500" || errCode == "404" || errCode == "403")
    {
        return View($"~/Views/Error/{errCode}.cshtml");
    }

    return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
}
```

And I have a simple error page 403.cshtml under /Views/Error/ folder.

But none of them works, all display this page:
[image]

I am wondering if something I missed or forgot to implement for display a formatted error page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting an `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the `Error` action?

Comment: Oh. no I didn't. But would the global authentication/authorization disable AllowAnonymous anyway?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Probably with a try though.

Comment: It works, I just checked again, AllowAnonymous means it will not get deny access for anonymous for the places it is used. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure but there should be 2 variations of windows authentications:

1. The host only allows authenticated users

   - When you enable `Windows Authentication` and disable `Anonymous Users`
   - `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` no effect, because unauthenticated requests never reach your application
   - Hence you can't / don't need to set up global filter. You might have to setup the friendly error pages on the server?

     ```cs
     public class Startup
     {
         public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

         public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             Configuration = configuration;
         }

         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
         {
             services.AddMvc();
         }

         public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
         {
             if (env.IsDevelopment())
             {
                 app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
             }
             else
             {
                 app.UseExceptionHandler("/home/error");
             }

             app.UseStaticFiles();

             app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoutes();
         }
     }
     ```
2. The host allows both anonymous and authenticated users

   - When you enable both `Windows Authentication` and `Anonymous Users`
   - `[Authorize]` requires additional setup on `Startup.cs`

     ```cs
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

         services.AddMvc(config =>
         {
             var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireRole("Application - Administrator")
                .Build();

             config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
         });
     }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
     {
         ...

         app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error", "?code={0}");

         app.UseAuthentication();

         app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoutes();
     }
     ```
   - You need to use `[AllowAnonymous]` on the error controller to override the `[Authorize]` global filter to allow anonymous requests.

     ```cs
     [AllowAnonymous]
     public class ErrorController : Controller
     {
         public IActionResult Index(int? code)
         {
             ...
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: Thank you David, I think I am on the 2nd approach, which I was missing the AllowAnonymous attribute for Error ActionMethod by default created by .Net Core project template in HomeController

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the Error method, it missed the AllowAnonymous attribute to allow anonymous access to the error method when the user failed authorization.
Credit to @Calc

Answer (score 1):

Try `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");` in startup.configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)

Works on ASP.NET CORE2.0 web app

It will handle any kind of HTTP error